# Git fails to push to ftp-server

Tags: git, ftp

I've got some problem using git over ftp.

What I've got right now:

- FTP Server, ready for active and passive FTP;
- Bare git repository, one commit

The repository was created locally and then sent to the server. 
I had to use git update-server-info to make it work.
Now I can clone into my new repository and execute pulls, but I cannot push. Everytime I try, git says:

`error: Cannot access URL ftp://f***@w*****/repo/, return code 3
fatal: git-http-push failed`

Can anyone please help me?

Greets Florian

Comment: I can't help but notice that http-pushing onto an ftp server does look like an awkward mix of protocol.

Comment: Where did you get your git binaries? I think it have to compile with curl support to get ftp works.

Comment: @user502515 , it is normal. git use the same backend for (dumb) http and ftp.

Comment: does curl only affect push? because otherwise, pull shouldn't work either

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Note: if your goal is to copy (deploy) files that have changed in your local repo to a ftp server then:

- [git-ftp (python script)](https://github.com/ezyang/git-ftp)
- [git-ftp (shell script)](https://github.com/resmo/git-ftp)
- [git-deploy (ruby script)](https://github.com/mislav/git-deploy)
- [PHPloy (php script)](https://github.com/banago/PHPloy)
- [Webdrive](http://blog.wekeroad.com/2009/11/23/deploying-a-web-application-with-git-and-ftp)

might be better suited for this task.

As far as I know (as [confirmed in this thread](http://blog.wekeroad.com/2009/11/23/deploying-a-web-application-with-git-and-ftp)), there is no support yet for git push to ftp.

Comment: hm, no, I planned to use the ftp server as "central" repository. 

as far as I know, ftp was added to git some months ago (see http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-push.html#URLS ).

I tried msysgit and the standard ubuntu 10.04 package (1.7.0.4) for my tests

Comment: @Tornado: I did read that git push man page, but I haven't found any other indication that ftp is supported for push (fetch yes, clone yes, but push?)

Answer (score 4):

@VonC: Seems you're right, I talked so some GIT guys on IRC and they told me the same. FTP pull works, FTP push doesn't. But anyway, your confirmation thread is a possible solution to my problem, as I can use webdrive/netdrive (and curlftpfs on linux) to make git think the remote repository is a local folder. This is the only solution I see at the moment.

Thank you!

Comment: interesting: you could later expand this answer to include some implementation and settings details to achieve that remote repo installation.

Comment: Okay, here some details: I only tried under windows so far as linux really sucks on my eee-pc (primary much battery lifetime is lost). But anyway, on windows it's straight-forward: I used Netdrive because a free-for-home-use license is available. With netdrive, I connected to my ftp-server (set it to some drive letter) and then used this now "local" drive as a remote repository (using git clone x:/repo.git in my working directory). That's it. I assume that it works as well mounting some ftp directory with curlftpfs under linux.