# how to use git for uploading to server without involving FTP client

Tags: git

Right now i am using FileZilla client to upload files to the server. I want to involve GIT, so that i commit the files locally and then through GIT it should uploaded to my server. What are the steps to achieve this goal.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does GIT support push to an ftp server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664251/does-git-support-push-to-an-ftp-server)

Comment: My question is different to this. I want to use GIT and GITHUB and get rid of FTP client. Files should be uploaded to the server. What will be the configuration for GIT.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deploy a project using Git push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279169/deploy-a-project-using-git-push)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+push+to+deploy+hook