# Windows Git with external file locations

Tags: git, ftp

I'm using Git GUI on windows. My projects lie on an external linux server like this:

/home/site_dev
/home/site_prod

When editing the PHP, JS and CSS files, I simply use a text editor which supports FTP open/save.

How can I use Git to manage my projects? The "Create New Repository" only allows me to chose local file locations.

Comment: You will need shell access. Can you SSH to the remote host?

Comment: is your linux box the final site?

Comment: The linux box contains both development and production files (/home/site_dev and /home/site_prod).

Comment: when answering a comment use @mrbay so that the guy gets notified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to work on the project is to clone the project to a local directory, work, commit, and then deploy and/or push to the server.

Cloning can be done from a FTP, just do:

```
git clone ftp://user@server/project.git
```

And it will clone the project to a new directory inside your current one.

Once changes are committed, just `git push origin` to propagate changes back to the server.

Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5141205/11343) for discussion on git remote repositories on a ftp server.

EDIT

If you want to do everything remotely, your best bet is to mount the FTP location as a network drive, and provide it to git interface. See [this article](http://smallvoid.com/article/ftp-map-network-drive.html) for solutions. There may be some hicups though, due to limitations of the FTP protocol. It maybe worth sharing your files with Samba if you meet problems with FTP.

Comment: But I do not want to work on the files locally. I edit the files directly on the remote server.