# i cannot push a changes to a git repository using ftp

Tags: git, ftp, push, atlassian-sourcetree

[image]

Over the server i can change files, commit them, and push to origin. But from local repo using source tree i cannot. Local repo's commit works fine. But what to do to be able pushing? It should work because i cloned the repo and it was fine.

```
Pushing to ftp://annejulie%40blue-world.pl:password@blue-world.pl/annejulie.blue-world.pl.git
error: Cannot access URL ftp://annejulie%40blue-world.pl:password@blue-world.pl/annejulie.blue-world.pl.git/, return code 3
fatal: git-http-push failed
error: failed to push some refs to 'ftp://annejulie%40blue-world.pl:password@blue-world.pl/annejulie.blue-world.pl.git'
```

`git remote -v` will output:

```
 origin ../annejulie.blue-world.pl.git (fetch)
 origin ../annejulie.blue-world.pl.git (push)`
```

Comment: Please, add the error message as a text so the exception will be searchable in Stack Overflow/Google/Bing/etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, according to [Git fails to push to ftp-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4315413/git-fails-to-push-to-ftp-server) **there is no possibilities** to push via ftp account.

According to [git-scm.com - GIT URLS](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch):

`Git supports ssh, git, http, and https protocols (in addition, ftp, and ftps can be used for fetching and rsync can be used for fetching and pushing, but these are inefficient and deprecated; do not use them).`